# Persist checkbox state while jsp reload

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have code where I want to keep more than one checkboxes state(checked) when the jsp page reloads after coming back from controller.I can successfuly retrieve the selected values in sesssion but am unable to get the check boxes checked.
My code snippet is as follows:

```
<%!public String portarray[] = null;%>  
<%if (request.getSession().getAttribute("portselected") != null) {
            portarray = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("portselected");
for (int i = 0; i < portarray.length; i++) {%>
  alert(
    <%=portarray[i]%>
  );
$("#\"removebasket"+<%=portarray[i]%>+"\"").attr("checked", true);
$('#removebasket13989')[0].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly use document.ready to only do this when the page is fully loaded.
also, use .prop() for setting the check state

```
// only when page fully loads
$(document).ready(function() {
   // use prop
   $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

you should also make sure that `$("#\"removebasket"+<%=portarray[i]%>+"\"")` is correct byt viewing the source of your page when it reloads

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for your help. Its working now. But now the issue is its working with ie, not with chrome. Could you please suggest some solution for these.